# PHP и JSON для андроид

Tags: android

Есть PHP страница, где я запросом получаю записи из MySQL и декодирую это все в JSON.

Если в браузере открыть эту страницу, то данные выводятся в JSON формате в таком виде \u0441\u0432 все символы.

Как использовать получаемый JSON в андроид приложении для вывода данных в список? Как-то может дополнительно нужно подготовить JSON или что делать после того как PHP страница выдает данные в JSON?

Код PHP

```
<?php

$host = 'localhost';
$db   = 'mydb';
$user = 'myuser';
$pass = 'mypass';
$charset = 'utf8';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt = [
PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];

$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

$response = array();

$result = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM c068t_k2_items where catid = 6");
$response["items"] = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    //print_r($response);
$product = array();
    $product["id"] = $row["id"];
    $product["title"] = $row["title"];
    $product["catid"] = $row["catid"];
    $product["published"] = $row["published"];
    $product["introtext"] = $row["introtext"];
    array_push($response["items"], $product);
}
$response["success"] = 1;
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Ответ

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Заголовок",
      "catid": 6,
      "published": 1,
      "introtext": "Текст"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Заголовок",
      "catid": 6,
      "published": 1,
      "introtext": "Текст"
    }
  ],
  "success": 1
}
```

Comment: А вы пробовали обрабатывать это уже на андроиде? То что вы привели в пример (`\u0441` и прочее) это символы в юникоде. Если вы вставите в строку в андроиде `String s = "hello \u0441";`, этот символ автоматически привратится в символ из кода.

Comment: Пока не пробовал, я вожусь еще с выборкой всех нужных данных из БД. А ваш ответ понятен, но я спрашивал несколько другое

Ранее я работал в андроид с json только закидывал файлы json в assets и обрабатывал, а сейчас предстоит с хостинга получать и в этом смысле имелось ввиду нужны ли дополнительные действия для получения файла json. Но вроде нашел один пример, где указывается прямая ссылка на php файл, который возвращает JSON и уже идет обработка

Comment: Кстати это нормальный способ? Указать в коде ссылку на PHP файл и дальше обрабатывать?

Comment: `указать в коде ссылку на php файл` -- вы знакомы с http-запросами, rest api и прочим? Вам нужно делать запрос с андроида на ваш сервер (или хостинг), обрабатывать ответ, и уже работать с json-ом. А со стороны сервера нужно эти запросы получать и давать ответы

Comment: Мало знаком как это все делается в андроид, поэтому говорю нашел пример где прямо в коде указана ссылка на php файл. А т.к. мало знаком с тем как писать подобного рода приложения и спрашивал можно ли так?

А так я подготовил PHP страничку который возвращает json данные это и есть ведь API? Во всяком случае я так понял

Comment: Если вы укажете просто ссылку на php файл, тогда нужно чтобы этот файл обрабатывал гет-запрос. Сейчас напишу ответ

Comment: Я в вопрос добавил PHP код, который выдает мне данные в JSON формате. Вот имея этот код и то что он возвращает мне нужно обработать получаемые JSON данные

Comment: @Kolhoznik сразу посоветую вам посмотреть на Retrofit для андроида.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим, ваш php-файл доступен по адресу `http://mysite.com/files/test.php` и он отдаёт JSON, который вам нужно обработать.

Не буду вдаваться в сложные подробности, как работать с бэкэндом, обрабатывать запросы и формировать ответы разберитесь сами, я лишь приведу простейший пример.

Делаем запрос с Android:

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url("http://mysite.com/files/test.php")
    .build();

client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
    @Override public void onFailure(Request request, Throwable throwable) {
        throwable.printStackTrace(); // выводим ошибку
    }

    @Override 
    public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
        // проверяем, нормальный ли пришел ответ
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

        // если нормальный, получаем тело ответа
        String responseString = response.body().string();

        // парсим json
        JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject(responseString);
        JSONArray items = responseJson.getJSONArray("items");
        // и так далее уже парсите ваш жсон
    }
});
```

Это самый простой пример, для тренировки. Если вы пишете своё API и потом собираетесь с ним взаимодейстовать, посмотрите в сторону Retrofit, [вот хороший гайд](https://habrahabr.ru/post/314028/). С бэкендом на php, я думаю, вы сами разберетесь :)

Comment: Понял примерно принцип работы. Попробую реализовать для своего примера. Спасибо

Comment: Абсолютно верно,правда я раньше описал схожее)

Comment: Ссылка тоже полезная.. Буду изучать. Спасибо

Comment: Но я ведь правильно понимаю, если мне просто нужно тупо отобразить пока что данные JSON вашего ответа достаточно, ну за исключением того что докончить его нужно

Comment: @Kolhoznik моего ответа более чем достаточно, да - вы можете просто строку отобразить, например, в TextView, а потом уже сами решаете что делать. Если ответ отвечает на поставленный вопрос, поставьте галочку (находится она чуть левее ответа).

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то нужно:
1)Достать JSON из PHP файла(методом get).Можно HttpClient httpclient и дальше.
2)После request метода Get-Добавить в Буффер стринг(buffer) например этот JSON.
3)Создать JSON обьект у себя в приложении , типа JSONObject jsonAnswer=new JSONObject(buffer.toString());
4)Парсить этоn JSON, типа
String res=jsonAnswer.getString("title").toString();/
5)А потом добавить полученные значения res в ArrayList например, затем можно втыкать в список.